# count from the list

Tags: html, xpath

Say I have a xpath like below

```
//div[contains(@class, 'cat 53453463')]/a
```

and the page contains many of these with different Xes

```
//div[contains(@class, 'cat xxxxxx')]/a
```

Does xpath have any feature to count how far down the list it is? for example if in the list below my match is the 7th row. Does xpath have anything for getting that or is this something I should code manually?

```
//div[contains(@class, 'cat xxxxxx')]/a
//div[contains(@class, 'cat xxxxxx')]/a
//div[contains(@class, 'cat xxxxxx')]/a
//div[contains(@class, 'cat xxxxxx')]/a
//div[contains(@class, 'cat xxxxxx')]/a
//div[contains(@class, 'cat xxxxxx')]/a
//div[contains(@class, 'cat 53453463')]/a
//div[contains(@class, 'cat xxxxxx')]/a
```

Here is a real world example

Take this page

http://newyork.backpage.com/homes-for-sale/

and we run the following xpath on it

```
//div[contains(@class, 'cat 93893742')]/a
```

At the time of posting this, the match is the 7th listing. Is there anyway to get the xpath return 7 since it's the 7th listing?

Comment: Let me rephrase to see I have the question correct: You want to know, of the elements which match, say, `//div[contains(@class, 'cat')]/a`, the index of the element in that list which also matches `//div[contains(@class, 'cat 53453463')]/a`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think that's also a way of doing it. I'm scraping a classified site, and I want to know which listing position it has on the page.

Comment: It's hard to answer without seem some example HTML the XPath is running against. We don't really have a way of testing our ideas.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I edited my question to include a real world example

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0 you can get the position of a node $N within a node-list $L using the expression

```
for $i in 1 to count($L) return $i[$L[$i] is $N]
```

I don't think it can be done in XPath 1.0 (but I've been wrong before...)

Comment: I updated my question with a real world example. How about using preceding-sibling? would that not be more simple?

Comment: You haven't shown your source document so we have no way of knowing if the selected elements are siblings.