# finding the current position of xpath match

Tags: xpath, htmlunit

I'm trying to get the current position of a xpath match. Here is a real world example

on this page http://newyork.backpage.com/homes-for-sale/

running the following xpath matches the 8th listing counting from top

```
//div[contains(@class, 'cat 93893742')]
```

I want to somehow get the ad position using xpath which at the time of posting this question is "8". I tried using `prececeding-sibling::div` but I am getting unexpected results.

Anyway to achieve this with xpath?

Comment: That URL gave "404 not found" for me

Comment: @har07 very strange, maybe they disallow traffic from some countries

Comment: Yep, seems like it. The base URL gave "restricted access" for me (Indonesia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure wether current version of `htmlunit` supports `XPath 2.0`, but if so you can use below expression:

```
index-of(//div[starts-with(@class, "cat")], //div[@class='cat 93893742'])
```

This will return `10` - position in common list

If you want to get position in list for specific date (`Thu. May. 11`) you can try:

```
index-of(//div[normalize-space()="Thu. May. 11"]/following::div[starts-with(@class, "cat")],//div[normalize-space()="Thu. May. 11"]/following::div[@class='cat 93893742'])
```

which returns `8`

Comment: thanks for your answer but it looks like HtmlUnit uses Xalan-Java for Xpath and Xalan-Java does not support Xpath 2 yet

Comment: I will use Java to solve this problem, but your anwer works with xpath 2 so I'll mark it as correct. Here is the way I'll do it 
List listings = page.getByXPath("//div[starts-with(@class,'cat')]");
use a loop to count and I will get the desired results

Answer (score 0):

Based on this and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925916/count-from-the-list), maybe the following XPath is what you're looking for :

```
count(
    //div[contains(@class, 'cat 93893742')]/preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'cat ')]
)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some description added in @har07 answer

I think this is what you required

```
count(//div[contains(@class, 'cat 93893742')]/preceding-sibling::div[starts-with(@class,'cat')])+1
```

Lets breakdown the whole

```
//div[contains(@class, 'cat 93893742')]
```

will match the required context node  which have classname = cat 93893742

```
/preceding-sibling::div[starts-with(@class,'cat')]
```

Will match the all `div` element starts with `classname=cat` just before your context node

So if we keep all those in `count()` it will count all div tag just before the context node So add 1 to include count of context node as well

If you want to point that element by using index like calculated above then add this

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'cat')][count(//div[contains(@class, 'cat 93893742')]/preceding-sibling::div[starts-with(@class,'cat')])+1]
```

Equal to

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'cat')][10]   // 10 in index number
```